# COM + WaitForSingleObject

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, com, synchronization

I've been trying to find a good architecture for one application for the last few days, and after some research I'm finally stuck, and the reason is COM.

The app in question will have multiple GUI threads, and they will schedule work items for worker thread. The worker thread will initialize COM via CoInitialize(NULL);, create few COM components and will go into a loop which will wait for WaitForMultipleObjects(2, ...) (ExitEvent - to indicate that app is shutting down and ManualResetEvent - to indicate that there are actually work items to process), and on successful wait, will process the items and PostMessage them back to GUI threads. The ManualResetEvent will be reset inside worker if the queue will be empty and will happen inside queue critical section.

The problem is that COM, as usual, makes EVERYTHING 1000x harder...

If I understand correctly, CoInitialize(NULL); creates a hidden window, and any message posted during WaitForSingle/MultipleObject/s can cause a deadlock.

So, I need to call the MsgWaitForMultiple objects. Which in turn can fail if messages are not pumped correctly. Unfortunately, I can't quite understand how to pump them in a correct way. Do I have to create my own message loop? Will the app crash if COM decides to create a messagebox?

So far it seems I have to proceed like this?

```
HANDLE hEvents[2] = {};

int ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam) {
    int nRetVal = 0;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CComPtr<ISomething> smthn;
    smthn.CoCreateInstance(...);

    MSG msg = {};

    bool bRun = true;

    while(bRun) {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, ??NULL/-1??, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) { /*Which one here?*/
            if(msg.Message == WM_QUIT) {
                bRun = false;
                nRetVal = msg.wParam;
                break;
            }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if(MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2, &hEvents, ...)) {
            if(exitevent) { bRun = false; nRetVal = 0; }
            else if(processevent) { [processdata] }
        }
    }

    smthn.release();

    CoUninitialize();
    return nRetVal;
}
```

But what about hidden window, messageboxes, am I even on the right path?

Comment: Do the COM objects move from thread to thread?  Or do they live an die within a single thread?  What do the COM objects do, in a nutshell?  I think your architecture is far afield, because you've gotten some bad advice on SO.

Comment: I don't get the question.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Also, please explain "multiple GUI threads."  Are you simply referring to the hidden COM window, or are you really trying to have multiple main GUI threads?

Comment: @Hans:  Check Madman's previous posts from the last couple days to get a handle on where this post came from.

Comment: The COM objects live and die within a thread. MSXML is one of them, but there are others I have no control over. They are not guaranteed to be COINIT_MULTITHREADED safe.

Comment: The problem is that I'm kinda lost with the COM and thread/synchronization stuff. I can't have those components on the main GUI thread, and every solution I come up with has "Don't ever do it" warning in MSDN docs.

Comment: Multiple GUI threads, as someone might create a new window on new thread, and still queue some work items to this worker thread.

Comment: I have never heard of a single application having multiple GUI threads.  Are you really sure you need and want this?

Comment: Probably not, but I want to design the worker thread in a way that it doesn't matter who calls it, and how. So that's why I wrote multiple GUI threads, it would have been more correct to say that any thread can queue work items to my thread. And my thread is doing COM and logic encapsulation and is isolated from GUI.

Comment: I actually prefer your solution to the one marked as correct. The HWND to pass is NULL (to ensure messages for all windows on the thread are pumped) and the message filtering is also going to prevent windows get ting messages they were legitimately sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like overkill, but this worked for me :

```
int     waitAndDispatch( HANDLE* event_handle, unsigned int ev_count, DWORD timeout )
{
    int     rval = -1;
    bool    bLoop = true;       // if the loop should terminate

    HANDLE* pHList = new HANDLE[ev_count];
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < ev_count; ++i )
    {
        pHList[i] = event_handle[i];
    }

    while( bLoop )
    {
        DWORD res = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects( ev_count, pHList, false, timeout, QS_ALLPOSTMESSAGE | QS_SENDMESSAGE );
        if( res == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + ev_count )       // messages arrived
        {
            MSG tmpMsg;
            bool hasMsg = true;
            while( bLoop && hasMsg )
            {
                ::PeekMessage( &tmpMsg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE );
                if( ::PeekMessage( &tmpMsg, 0, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_REMOVE ) ||     // WM_USER for COM
                    ::PeekMessage( &tmpMsg, 0, 0, WM_KEYFIRST - 1, PM_REMOVE )      // all destroy update, ...
                    )
                {
                    DWORD val = ::WaitForMultipleObjects( ev_count, pHList, false, 0 );
                    if( val >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && val <= (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + ev_count) )
                    {
                        rval = val - WAIT_OBJECT_0;
                        bLoop = false;
                    }
                    ::DispatchMessage( &tmpMsg );
                }
                else
                {
                    hasMsg = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if( res >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && res < (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + ev_count) )
        {
            rval = res - WAIT_OBJECT_0;
            bLoop = false;
        }
        else if( res == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
        {
            rval = ev_count;
            bLoop = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rval = -1;
            bLoop = false;
        }
    }
    delete[] pHList;

    return rval;
}
```

I had to write this piece for VB6 and its thread interactions over com compartments ... .

If you initialize your thread apartment with `CoInitializeEx( 0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED )`, your COM calls will not be queued into an message queue. But then you have the problem of objects created in different COM apartments. These need to be marshaled ... .

Comment: Can you recommend me an article I could try to read? I would like to understand the different arguments and internals of that routing better, like when to remove messages and when not. Like why >// WM_USER for COM

Comment: Years ago, when I wrote that code, i couldn't find anything on this behavior. It took me days of debugging deep in COM/VB6 to come up with a solution. Nowadays I would likely approach problems with this, by creating a(/several) dedicated threads separating GUI/COM objects, just to get around the whole apartment model of COM.

Comment: -1 for bizzare message filtering thats going to break - for no good reason - any other message windows that use messages > WM_USER (such as the WM_APP range).

Comment: Yes, I know. This is extremely bizarre, but your comment is wrong. Only messages < WM_KEYFIRST (0x00FF) and the message WM_USER are dispatched. Sure, do it the right way. Do not let COM objects and COM calls cross thread/apartment boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`CoWaitForMultipleHandles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it will do the necessary message pumping on the hidden COM window for inter-thread syncing.

The hidden window is of class `OleMainThreadWndClass` with `OleMainThreadWndName` as caption but on win9x its class is `WIN95 RPC Wmsg`. It's hidden which means you can't use straight `EnumThreadWindows` to find it.