# WaitForMultipleObjects and COM

Tags: c++, com

I'm trying to make a named pipe server. Examples on MSDN use the [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) or similar functions. There is a warning considering use of the function together with COM objects. And I indeed use COM in my application.

> Use caution when calling the wait functions and code that directly or indirectly creates windows. If a thread creates any windows, it must process messages. Message broadcasts are sent to all windows in the system. A thread that uses a wait function with no time-out interval may cause the system to become deadlocked. Two examples of code that indirectly creates windows are DDE and the CoInitialize function. Therefore, if you have a thread that creates windows, use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects or MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx, rather than WaitForSingleObject.

The MsgWaitForMultipleObjects seems to return on receiving some messages, but it is unclear what I'm supposed to do in respond to them.

In [COM + WaitForSingleObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814425/com-waitforsingleobject) it was suggested to use [CoWaitForMultipleHandles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cowaitformultiplehandles?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and it actually shall do something with messages for the hidden COM window.

What is the proper way to implement waiting functionality in an application that uses COM objects? Is CoWaitForMultipleHandles sufficent for this?

Comment: This is only for STA/threads. But CoWaitForMultipleHandles handles all cases so it's probably the best: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tapi/hints-and-tips

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you. I was just unsure because Microsoft didn't mention the function on the WaitForMultipleObjects, only Msg... ones.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/wxutil.cpp#L589-L686) can give some insight.